# Google Script - Multi cells copy from a sheet to another with "if empty" check

Tags: google-apps-script

First of all I would to thanks to community of Stack Overflow. 
The many posts here helped to build an billing data file in Google spreadsheet with Scripts to convert invoices to pdf, send them by email, clear specific cells of the invoice after pdf generation, etc.

However, I am struggling now to export sales data from the Invoice to 2 other sheets (Sales and Products) to be able to make some analysis

Invoice looks like this:
[Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFMv9.png)
It can contain 1 to 10 lines of different products

**Here is the link to my spreadsheet:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11MDwYbCDHJy0rUtnYWEk4k8Ow0KvppNSu13B7uZWU1g/edit?usp=sharing

**What I want to do:**

1. **for each non-empty line** of sheet "INVOICE", I want to copy specific cells to sheet "SALES" that contains following info: `Invoice #, Date, Name, Surname, Email, Ref, Product name, Quantity, Total price after rebate, Mode of payment`

I want 1 line / product sold
Hence, if 2 products references are sold, I will have to copy `"Invoice #, Date, Name, Surname, Email and Mode of payment"` twice

I tried using several functions (lastrow,etc.) but this is not a basic copy (for me at least) as I am not copying an entire row

To make it simple, I ended up writing a script that copy the 10 lines of the invoice (no matter they are empty or not)
But this gives me 2 problems: my script takes ~20 sec to run and it copies `Invoice #, Date, Name,...` for lines that have no sales data
Then I have to delete manually these lines. If I create a script to delete these lines, that would be even slowlier

2. In Sales sheet, I have Vlookup formulas (yellow columns) that I would like to be copied down when I create a new row or add data in a new row
   Again, I couldn't do that
3. In sheet "Products", adjust the inventory quantity each time I sell a product
   For this purpose, I have created a column "Sold qtties" (Column E) that I would like to increment by the qtties sold in the invoice

I would really appreciate if some of you could help me here.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Your code was very slow because you process single data instead of multiples.
Also for your formula issues, I change them using ARRAYFORMULA

Here is your modified code:

```
        function myFunction() {
      var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sheetName = "INVOICE";
      var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);


      // Copy each  sales lines to 'SALES' sheet
      var destinSheet = "SALES";
      var cibleSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(destinSheet);
      var cibleSheetRange = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(destinSheet);

      //DEBUT MODIFS
      var sourceSheetData = sourceSheet.getRange("A13:H22").getValues();
      var numInvoice = sourceSheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
      var dateInvoice = sourceSheet.getRange("F3").getValue();
      var typePaiement = sourceSheet.getRange("C26").getValue();
      var surName = sourceSheet.getRange("F7").getValue();
      var lastName = sourceSheet.getRange("F8").getValue();
      var email = sourceSheet.getRange("F9").getValue();
      var invoiceLine1 = [];
      var invoiceLine2 = [];
      var invoiceLine3 = [];
      var lines =0;
      var lastRow = cibleSheet.getLastRow();

  for(var i=0;i<sourceSheetData.length;i++){
     if(sourceSheetData[i][0]!=""){
        lines= lines+1;
        cibleSheet.getRange(lastRow+lines,1 ,1,2).setValues([[numInvoice,dateInvoice]]);
        cibleSheet.getRange(lastRow+lines,5 ,1,5).setValues([[surName,lastName,email,sourceSheetData[i][1],sourceSheetData[i][2]]]);
        cibleSheet.getRange(lastRow+lines,11 ,1,3).setValues([[sourceSheetData[i][0],sourceSheetData[i][7],typePaiement]]);

        //INCREMENT STOCK
        //YOU ALSO COULD USE FORMULA  =sumifs(SALES!K:K;SALES!I:I;C2;SALES!J:J;B2)
        for (var j=0;j<stockSheetData.length;j++){
           if (sourceSheetData[i][1]==stockSheetData[j][0]){
           var oldSales= stockSheet.getRange(j+1,5).getValue();
           stockSheet.getRange(j+1,5).setValue(oldSales+sourceSheetData[i][0]);
           }
       }

     }
  }

}
```

You can test directly in your spreadsheet if all works as expected

Comment: Thank you very much ClemT. It is much faster now! It works perfectly except for 1 point: since column H ("TOTAL PRICE AFTER REBATE") is a formula (= selling price unit * qtties - rebate), the copy to second sheet doesn't work well (basically it copies the raw number, not the * qtties - rebate). Can you help please? :)

Comment: Hi benjaminV, sorry I have basically count the number of column without taking in account that you merge 3 of them. The code is fine now.

Comment: Hi benjaminV, I also add the code to sum up the sold quantities. If this is fine for you, please mark your question as solve.

Comment: Hi @ClemT Thank you very much for your help. And sorry for the merged columns, I should have seen it myself. Regarding the code to sum up the sold quantities, I wanted to know if that would be possible to paste it on a different column depending on the month of sales. Typically I would have "Sold January", "Sold February", ... and I would like the script to look for the invoice date and paste the info in a different column depending on the month. Obviously I could change my code every month but that is not really convenient. Do you know a solution? Then my script will be perfect! Thanks again

Comment: Hi @benjaminV . I could help on this too. But it's better to ask another question with this specific need ( the title of the present question will be not appropriate and people will not find answer) Maybe : copy data to a specific column depending on the month?

Comment: Hi benjamin , have you finally find a way to do what you want ? Still need help? Could you mark my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks ClemT. I have marked your answer. Nope I couldn't find the solution to my problem. I guess I will stick to a manual change every month